# Why is this jQuery $.click() running on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason my jQuery function is running on page load, rather than when being clicked. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KRvvg/

Here's the code:

```
var month = 'February';
var year = 2013;

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#moveMonthForward').click(moveMonthForwardFunction(month, year));

function moveMonthForwardFunction(month, year) {
                    var NextMonth = findNextMonth(month, year);
                    console.log('index.php?Year=' + NextMonth.Year + '&Month=' + NextMonth.Month);
                }

function findNextMonth(CurrentMonth, CurrentYear) {
                    switch (CurrentMonth) {
                        case 'January':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'February', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'February':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'March', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'March':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'April', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'April':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'May', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'May':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'June', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'June':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'July', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'July':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'August', 'Year': CurrentYear1 };
                            break;
                        case 'August':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'September', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'September':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'October', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'October':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'November', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'November':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'January', 'Year': CurrentYear };
                            break;
                        case 'December':
                            var NextMonth = { 'Month': 'January', 'Year': CurrentYear + 1 };
                            break;
                    }
                    return NextMonth;
                }
});
```

Comment: try `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: *"For some reason my jQuery function is running on page load"*: The reason is that you are calling the function. `(...)` after a function reference always calls the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of passing the callback `moveMonthForwardFunction` reference to the click method, you are invoking the `moveMonthForwardFunction` method and passing the value returned by it as the click handler.

You should pass a function reference to the click method as below

```
$('#moveMonthForward').click(function(){
    moveMonthForwardFunction(month, year)
});
```

Comment: And you could use `.on('click', function(){ ... });`